# Host key verification failed after changing MAC address

Tags: ssh, ip, git, mac-address

I changed my MAC address, I believe using `sudo ip link set dev interface address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`, in order to be assigned a new local IP address to fix some network issues I was having. This worked perfectly, and my network issues are fixed. However, I'm now having issues with SSH as a result.

If I `git pull origin master` from a GitHub remote, I get:

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '52.64.108.95'
Offending key for IP in /home/michael/.ssh/known_hosts:105
Matching host key in /home/michael/.ssh/known_hosts:166
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So not only does it refuse to connect, but also the RSA host key seems to never match the actual host. Even if I `ssh-keygen -f "~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "github.com"` and accept the new host key, this error persists.

However, if I change networks from wired (with the spoofed MAC address) to wireless (with the default address), I no longer get this problem.

Is my SSH key tied to my old MAC address? Or is GitHub itself noticing that I changed my MAC address and refusing to let me connect? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have multiple RSA keys? It could be possible that ssh is trying to use the wrong one.

Comment: could you attach git log running it with `GIT_TRACE=1 git ...`? Host key address should not change if you change network anyway.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Check if your **private** key has a line like `Private-MAC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` right at the end.</s>

Comment: are you sure that has anything to do with the MAC address of the computer, and isn't just  a MAC (message authentication code) of the key itself?

Comment: you're right - I was being retarded :)